# Is it possible to access variable data with appium?

Tags: appium, appium-android

My objective is to check the list content and click an element according to  its boolean variable state. 
I wonder whether it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming the state is stored as an attribute you can read and act upon it.

See http://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/commands/element/attributes/attribute/.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exact attribute you want to get. If Appium can parse it, then of course you can.

Here is an example with list of checkboxes:
[image]

So I want to click the ones that have `checked=true`:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElementsById("android:id/text1");
options.stream()
    .filter(e -> Boolean.valueOf(e.getAttribute("checked")) == true)
    .forEach(e -> e.click());
```